# Can I restore a Windows 95 MBR using a Windows XP installation disk?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, operating-systems, mbr

If I have Windows 95 installed on a temporary, secondary, FAT32 drive (which needs to go back into its original machine), can I repair its MBR using a Windows XP installation CD ROM?

Comment: Probably not.  Windows 95 was based on DOS and I do not think you will succeed fixing it with XP.

Comment: A Windows 95 floppy or ISO is trivial to find these days https://winworldpc.com/product/microsoft-windows-boot-disk/95-osr2x and then a simple `fdisk /mbr` should repair the MBR http://ps-2.kev009.com/pcpartnerinfo/ctstips/cde6.htm. Why do you need Windows XP?

Comment: @Mokubai This machine doesn't have a floppy drive.  When I try booting it with an external USB floppy drive (using a Windows 95 disk), the secondary hard drive with the suspected bad MBR is not visible.  (It IS visible after the Windows GUI boots.)  The original bad machine doesn't have a WORKING floppy drive at the moment.

Comment: @John I work at a manufacturing company and this 486 computer is hooked to a working, 30-year old device.  I don't want to spend significant time or money *attempting* to replace any of it when a simple DOS command might fix everything for another 10+ years.  I successfully imaged the bad hard drive and restored it to an IDE SSD.  Now I'm one mere DOS command away from making everybody happy. :)  May the StackExchange gods be kind...

Comment: You can download DOS 6.22, https://winworldpc.com/product/ms-dos/622. It can be installed in VirtualBox, https://www.instructables.com/How-To-Install-DOS-622-Under-VirtualBox/, and then, **perhaps**, used to fix the FAT32 drive... or not. Please let me know if that worked.

Comment: [Fix MS-DOS MBR Without DOS Boot Disk](https://superuser.com/q/746010/241386). Use `bootsect /nt52` or `bootsect /mbr` instead

Comment: @John I think we had a question some time back where someone needed to fix a windows 98 box that controlled a old saw. *could* You modernise the controller? maybe. Did it make sense to? apparently not.

Comment: @kackle123 Its been years since I used it but I recall some slightly dodgy dos livecds (and its possible freedos might be compatible enough to fix it). I also wonder if you can boot a 98 cd, it has a terminal/dos window option like windows XP. Another option might be to do a fresh install and copy over what's needed to that

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Dos/Win95/Win98 version of Testdisk:

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Read the contained manual and the online documentation at:

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

You could burn TestDisk on a CD-R and boot from your CD-ROM drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bootable DOS disk/diskette which has the `fdisk`
program on it, the MBR can be fixed by this simple command:

```
fdisk /mbr
```

Probably a Windows XP boot disk/floppy can also do it.
If not, you will need to create a Windows 95 virtual machine for that.
You might be able to find a ready-made such a VM on the internet.

Comment: At the moment, I don't have a working floppy drive; that's why I asked about the XP CD ROM that I have handy.

Comment: It might be enough, if you can create a bootable media with it.

Comment: Explain.  I have a Windows 95 boot floppy disk with fdisk.exe on it, but I have no usable floppy drive.  That's why I was asking about using a Windows XP CD ROM, which I have in my possession.

Comment: You could download a Windows 95 VM, for example [link1](https://archive.org/details/windows_95_vdi), [link2](https://archive.org/details/Microsoft_Windows_95_Virtual_Machine_VMware_WinWorld), [link3](http://virtualdiskimages.weebly.com/virtualbox.html). If you can manage to attach the bad disk to the VM, you might be able to make it work. (I never did it myself.)

Comment: You can make a bootable USB stick too.. I have one that boots DOS 7 (win9x dos).

Comment: @Señor CMasMas This old machine can't boot from a USB stick.